# Is it possible to change the label of points drawn by Here Maps in the directions API?

Tags: here-api

For this URL on the map each arrival point is displayed as "1" and "2" and "3" but I want to change the label "1" to "POINT A".

I would like to know if it is possible to include a parameter in the directions URL to change this label or if there is any other way?

https://www.here.com/directions/drive/52.412680999999985,16.923065/52.34958452562225,16.824127933791935/52.442618,16.85055500000001/52.452662,16.905487000000004/52.50284799999998,16.839568999999997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the label here. The wego.here.com portal can be used as is but it is not customizable in that detail.
We offer different services and APIs which you can use to create your own solution. Just have a look on our [developer.here.com](https://developer.here.com/) page for further information.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using the API to develop my own map customized.